# What does the phrase "Si rien ne vous appelle ailleurs" mean?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

"If you have no other business to attend to" is what it means? And is this phrase frequently used?

> « Si rien ne vous appelle ailleurs, pourquoi ne pas vous joindre aux festivités ? »

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"**Appeller**" here has the meaning of "**to call**" like in "*duty calls (me)*" : "*le devoir m'appelle*". It means you have to be somewhere or do something.

So "*Si rien ne vous appelle ailleurs*" basically means "*if you don't have to be somewhere else*".